# How to stop runnable object on click of back button

Tags: android

I am working on Media Player app where I am using the Runnable Thread as below :

```
private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {  <br>
          public void run() {  <br>
              try{  <br>
             startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();  <br>
             startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                toMinutes((long) startTime)))   <br>
             );  <br>
             seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);   <br>
             myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);   <br>
              }   <br>
              catch(Exception e){   <br>
                  e.printStackTrace(); <br>
              }  <br>
          }<br>
       }; <br>

In onDestroy() I have written the following code to stop the thread <br>
protected void onDestroy() { <br>
        super.onDestroy();<br>
        mediaPlayer.stop();<br>
        mediaPlayer.release();<br>
        myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(UpdateSongTime);<br>
        <br>
    }<br>
```

But on click of back button illegalstate exception occurs in runnable method at the statement

```
" startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();  ".  <br>
```

Can anyone help me how to stop runnable on back press   
Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make `Runnable UpdateSongTime`  as global variable

and put the following code in onFinish() or onDestroy()

```
if(UpdateSongTime != null)
  UpdateSongTime.interrupt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `UpdateSongTime.interrupt();`

Comment: In destroy() I tried to call interrupt , but that method is not available to updatesongtime at that time.